# Conditional adding certain data column from two data file

Tags: r

I have a question on conditional adding certain column from two data files. 
For instance, I have this data file:

Data 1

```
ID  purchased
1   5
2   3
3   3
4   3
5   3
6   4
7   4
8   4
9   4
10  4
```

Data 2

```
ID  Date3   Date4   Date5
1   2014    2013    2017
2   2014    2015    2012
3   2013    2016    2014
4   2015    2017    2014
5   2016    2012    2017
6   2017    2013    2017
7   2012    2013    2012
8   2014    2013    2014
9   2014    2015    2014
10  2015    2016    2015
```

So in the two files, the number on the purchase column (data 1) link to a specific date. For example, ID 1 purchased 5 (data 1) should link to ID 1 Date5 (data 2); ID 2 purchased 3 links to ID 2 Date3 (data 2), etc. So the results looks like below.

Result:

```
ID  purchased Date
1   5       2017
2   3       2014
3   3       2013
4   3       2015
5   3       2016
6   4       2013
7   4       2013
8   5       2014
9   5       2014
10  4       2016
```

I was thinking of using couple if statements like below:

```
if ((Data1$ID== Data2$ID) & Data1$purchased ==3) {
  Data1$Date<- Data2$Date3  
}
```

and do the same for purchased 4 and 5... I think i have the wrong approach and appreciate any help! I hope this makes sense. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please note that your example result is wrong in last col for values 8 and 9

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a more beautiful way but you can do like this:

```
Data1$Date <- ifelse(Data1$purchased==3,Data2$Date3,ifelse(Data1$purchased==4,Data2$Date4,Data2$Date5))
```

The condition is that your ID are sorted so you don't need to insert the condition on ID in the `ifelse` statement.

Answer (score 2):

If your order of date columns is in constant ascending order you could try:

```
k = Data1$purchased-1
Data1$year = sapply(seq_along(k),function(x) Data2[x,k[x]])
```

Or, if you want to match by column name:

```
k = match(Data1$purchased,as.numeric(gsub("Date","",colnames(Data2)[-1],fixed=TRUE)))
Data1$year = sapply(seq_along(k),function(x) Data2[x,k[x]+1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works if the order of ID's is different in both dataframes:

```
df$Date = sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) 
                  df1[df1$ID==df$ID[x],paste0("Date",df$purchased[x])])
```

Outut:

```
   ID purchased Date
1   1         5 2017
2   2         3 2014
3   3         3 2013
4   4         3 2015
5   5         3 2016
6   6         4 2013
7   7         4 2013
8   8         4 2013
9   9         4 2015
10 10         4 2016
```

Data:

```
df = read.table(text="ID  purchased
1   5
2   3
3   3
4   3
5   3
6   4
7   4
8   4
9   4
10  4",header=T)


df1 = read.table(text="ID  Date3   Date4   Date5
1   2014    2013    2017
2   2014    2015    2012
3   2013    2016    2014
4   2015    2017    2014
5   2016    2012    2017
6   2017    2013    2017
7   2012    2013    2012
8   2014    2013    2014
9   2014    2015    2014
10  2015    2016    2015",header=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways,

**Method 1, baseR - Vectorized by matching**

```
df$Date <- diag(as.matrix(df1[match(df$purchased, sort(unique(df$purchased)))+1]))
```

**Method 2, tidyverse - join**

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
 gather(var, val, -ID) %>% 
 left_join(mutate(df, purchased = paste0('Date', purchased)), ., 
                             by = c('ID' = 'ID', 'purchased' = 'var')) %>% 
 mutate(purchased = gsub('\\D+', '', purchased))
```

Both giving,

> ```
>    ID purchased Date
> 1   1         5 2017
> 2   2         3 2014
> 3   3         3 2013
> 4   4         3 2015
> 5   5         3 2016
> 6   6         4 2013
> 7   7         4 2013
> 8   8         4 2013
> 9   9         4 2015
> 10 10         4 2016
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `magrittr`:

- we first change the `purchased` column values in `data1` so it matches the columns of `data2`
- then we use `map2` to get the right element, and more specifically `map2_int` to have a vector as an output,
- then we append this vector to `data2`

code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
  mutate(purchased=paste0("Date",purchased)) %$%
  map2_int(ID,purchased, ~ data2[.x,.y]) %>%
  cbind(data1,.) %>%
  rename_("Date"= ".")
```

or a bit shorter, maybe more satisfying as we don't replug data1 midway:

```
data1 %>%
  mutate(d=paste0("Date",purchased)) %$%
  mutate(.,Date = map2_int(ID,d, ~ data2[.x,.y])) %>%
  select(-d)
```

And a one liner :

```
data1 %$% mutate(.,Date = map2(ID,purchased, ~ data2[.x,grep(.y,names(data2))]))
```

result:

```
#    ID purchased Date
# 1   1         5 2017
# 2   2         3 2014
# 3   3         3 2013
# 4   4         3 2015
# 5   5         3 2016
# 6   6         4 2013
# 7   7         4 2013
# 8   8         4 2013
# 9   9         4 2015
# 10 10         4 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R answer similar to soto's that uses matrix extraction.

```
dat1$Date <- dat2[cbind(match(dat1$ID, dat2$ID), dat1$purchased - 1)]
```

Here, we use a matrix to index the values inside of dat2, the date columns. We first match on IDs in dat1 to select the proper row, and then use the positions of the columns in dat2 in order to extract the proper column by subtraction.

this returns

```
dat1
   ID purchased Date
1   1         5 2017
2   2         3 2014
3   3         3 2013
4   4         3 2015
5   5         3 2016
6   6         4 2013
7   7         4 2013
8   8         4 2013
9   9         4 2015
10 10         4 2016
```

We can also use `match` in the second argument to find the matching index of the final character of the variable name in dat2 with the value of the purchased variable in dat1. This could be more flexible.

```
dat1$Date <- dat2[cbind(match(dat1$ID, dat2$ID),
                        match(as.character(dat1$purchased),
                              substring(names(dat2), nchar(names(dat2)))))]
```

**data**

```
dat1 <-
structure(list(ID = 1:10, purchased = c(5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "purchased"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

dat2 <- 
structure(list(ID = 1:10, Date3 = c(2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2012L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L), Date4 = c(2013L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 2016L), Date5 = c(2017L, 
2012L, 2014L, 2014L, 2017L, 2017L, 2012L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L
)), .Names = c("ID", "Date3", "Date4", "Date5"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```